# "Play" or "playing" – which one is correct and why?

Tags: grammar

> People often see him *play* basketball on the playground at the weekend.

Can I use *playing* instead?

Comment: Indeed you can, and in most contexts you *should* use ***playing*** here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What's the different of using play or playing in this context?

Comment: Both "play" and "playing" is correct here. People often see him (who is) playing basketball on the playground at the weekend. People often see him (who) play basketball on the playground at the weekend. So essentially both carry the same meaning.

Comment: @Jaugar: In your exact context there's not really any significant difference, but personally I'd slightly prefer infinitive ***play*** if it was an *organised, regular* activity, and continuous ***playing*** if it was something more *impromptu, irregular*. Compare to *"We often see him **drinking** in our local pub"*, where the infinitive would almost never be used. The infinitive emphasises that you saw the *activity*, rather than the *person [performing that activity]*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We can use either the infinitive without to or the -ing form after the
>   object of verbs such as hear, see, notice, watch. The infinitive
>   without to often emphasises the whole action or event which someone
>   hears or sees. The -ing form usually emphasises an action or event
>   which is in progress or not yet completed.
>
> - *He saw her drive off with a young man in the passenger seat.* (The speaker observed the whole event.)
> - *Maria heard him coming up the stairs towards her room, and felt scared.* (The action was in progress, happening, but not completed.)
>
> ([from *English Grammar Today*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/hear-see-etc-object-infinitive-or-ing))

Therefore, both forms are correct and have the same meaning. They might suggest different meanings when using them in past tense however.

Another thing:

> After can or could with one of these verbs, we always use the -ing
>   form, not the infinitive.

Comment: So you mean "I can hear you singing" is correct and "I can hear you sing" is wrong?

Comment: Thanks you guys! Now I can understand why my teacher suggested us using "play". In her point of view, people observed the fact of playing basketball.